# SQL Server insert into next column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

SQL Server 2012: is it possible to do a insert into select statement but insert data into the next column if the previous is already populated?

I have a table with a number of columns to store dates, I want to take data from another table and insert into the next available null date column.

Comment: why do you need such things...???

Comment: You probably want an update, not an insert. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are saying that the previous column is already populated, then you're really looking for some sort of update.  Try this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    col1 = CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 'value' ELSE col1 END,
    col2 = CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'value' ELSE col2 END;
```

The logic here is what you described, namely that we attempt to update `col1` with some value.  Should that column be empty, we make the update, otherwise we update `col2` instead.